# Is there a way to switch to charging only before plugging my phone into an USB?

Tags: usb, charging

Is there a way on Android 6.0 to switch to charging only before plugging my phone into an USB?

Comment: @beeshyams : I wrote Android 6 to signal the version. I edited to 6.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Enable developer options - To enable Developer Options, go to Settings and select About phone. Now, scroll down and find out Build number. Tap on this option around 7 times. You will get a success message
- You will find *Select USB configuration* . Tap on that too open a sub menu and choose *Charging only*
- Next time you connect, it will revert to charging automatically

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. I just did this right before updating to 7.0 so I hope I am remembering right. If you go to your developer options there should be an option to turn on or off what happens when you plug in your phone to a usb cord connected to a computer. You can switch it to charge only if you want. My current computer auto-encrypts anything plugged into it so I had to dig for this option. If it isn't in the Developer options, its in the USB connection options. Sorry I couldn't be more help.